# How to get the value of r, g, b seperately using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am trying to get the separate value of red for a pixel, the value of green for a pixel, and the value of blue for a pixel. for now, I get all three of them as a tuple. is there any way I can do this in PIL for python.

I've tried splitting the image using this

`r, g, b = im.split()`
`print(r)`
but it gives me <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=225x225 at 0x10E4DB0D0>
and I'm not sure what that is but the hexadecimal value seems to be the red value but my main purpose is to blend two images together by adding their separate r, g, b values in order to create a new image.

it seems like tuples cannot be added together as their addition is not of the values at a particular index but rather it just makes the value longer.

for example
`print(pixels[3, 3] + pixels2[3, 3])`
gives me `(255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255)`. (here pixels represent the image loaded.)
but I want to add the values together like 255+255 = 510 and then divide the value by two so that it can be in the range of rgb, but I can not add the values of the reds, greens and blues.

Comment: "but it gives me <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=225x225 at 0x10E4DB0D0>" Okay, and why is that wrong? What did you hope to see instead? What do you see if you just `print(im)`? Does that give you a better understanding of what is going on?

Comment: "it seems like tuples cannot be added together as their addition is not of the values at a particular index but rather it just makes the value longer." You can do this sort of thing with Numpy arrays. It seems like you should look up a general image processing tutorial instead.

Comment: "I want to add the values together like 255+255 = 510 and then divide the value by two so that it can be in the range of rgb, but I can not add the values of the reds, greens and blues." If the purpose is to *convert to greyscale*, then you should just say so. That is built-in, and you should read the documentation further to see how.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you for the tips. I'm not looking to convert the image into a grayscale image but I would definitely check out the Numpy arrays you recommended. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a tuple of R/G/B components, you can get the individual values either by indexing (`r = pixels[3,3][0]`) or unpacking (`r, g, b = pixels[3,3]`).